# Convolution of f(-x) with delta

Tags: convolution, dirac-delta

i'm struggling with the following convolution:

$\ f(-x,-y)* \delta(x,y-a)$

I don't know if it should be solved that way:

1. $\ f(-x,-(y-a))=f(-x,-y+a) $

or: (just the shifting)

2. $\ f(-x, -y-a) $

Comment: Have you tried to express the convolutions as integrals as were $\delta$ an ordinary function to see what happens?